# Add custom Jquery file to joomla 3

Tags: jquery, joomla3.0

I am trying to add a custom jquery file into joomla!. I have added the following into the templates/theme/index.php just before the

```
    <?php
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScript('templates/theme1982/js/add.js');
?>

  <jdoc:include type="head" />
```

The following jquery is what i am testing to figure this out:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ppp').click(function(event) {
      $("#ppp").toggleClass("mmm");
    }); 
});
```

With the html:

```
<div id="ppp">f</div>
```

and CSS :

```
.mmm {
    transform:rotate(45deg);
    background: green;
    }
    #ppp {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background: pink;   
        }
```

The add.js file seems to be present in the google source view and has the jquery text in the file however the function does not work

http://arete-sub.multi-web-service.co.uk/professional-services/management-training

Comment: You have to use "jQuery" instead of "$" .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joomla loads jquery in noconflict mode.

You have to change your code to:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery('#ppp').click(function(event) {
     jQuery("#ppp").toggleClass("mmm");
   }); 
});
```

Reference: [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)